# Showing csv file on map

Tags: openlayers-2, csv

Does OpenLayers support the uploading and rendering of CSV files? If it does, how?

I used this code and it didn't help.

```
var curLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("layer", {
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "test.txt",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.Text()
    })
});
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Comment: One observation, you create the layer curLayer, but then you add layer to the map.

Comment: yea, i just add code from and forgot to change all variables. but it's not that problem, i just mistyped here, i didn't mistyped in code where i work. but thanks for observation :)

Answer (score 2):

yes it does. as John Barça mentioned correct your map.addLayer section.

here a working example of mine:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("POIs", {
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({resFactor: 1.1})],
                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                        url: "data/textfile.txt",
                        format: new OpenLayers.Format.Text()
                    })
                });

                map.addLayer(layer);
```

content of the txt-file:

```
point   title   description icon    iconSize
47,12   mein titel1 meine beschreibung1 data/img/blue.png   15,20
50,13   mein titel2 meine beschreibung2 data/img/gray.png   15,20
54,12   mein titel3 meine beschreibung3 data/img/green.png  15,20
56,9    mein titel4 meine beschreibung4 data/img/red.png    25,35
53,7    mein titel6 meine beschreibung6 data/img/yellow.png 15,20
```

http://docs.openlayers.org/library/overlays.html#transition-markers-to-vectors

http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Text-js.html

[image]

Comment: I've tried that code, didn't help. I've also tried with strategies: strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()], no good. The problem that might be is: i recieved excel file with csv extension and in that file, values are separated with comma. That file was downloaded from geoserver. Also csv is Comma Separated Values, and i guess i'm not supposed to change the csv file, to delete that commas. Btw, i have read that documentation already, but thanks :)